# Printing each expense name and amount from a JS object that is saved from user input

Tags: javascript, html

Good morning!

I am halfway through my first JS app and have run into a problem. I am having a hard time printing multiple user inputs that I am putting into a JS object and printing both the obj.name and obj.amount to their respective places. I am able to print single items to their areas, but it puts the new one in each time instead of adding the new input onto the old. I have tried different things like putting the input directly into an array obj and then using a for loop and putting both the inputs into a separate var and pushing that into the previously created array. I have even tried console.log to see what it is taking from the input and it logs only the first letter of the string. I would appreciate any help with getting this to work. Thanks.

Here is what I have so far.

```
let expenseNames = [];
function incomingExpenses() {
        expenseNames.name = document.querySelector("[name=expense_Name]").value,
        expenseNames.amount= document.querySelector("[name=expense_Value]").value
    
    for (var i = 0; i <expenseNames['amount'].length; i++){
    document.querySelector('#title_Expenses').innerHTML = expenseNames.name;
    document.querySelector('#value_Expenses').innerHTML = expenseNames.amount;
    console.log(expenseNames['name'][i]);
    i++;
    }
};

let outgoingCalcButton = document.getElementById('expenseButton');
expenseButton.addEventListener("click", incomingExpenses);
```

```
<body>
    <h1>Budget Application</h1>
    <div id="inputSections" class="inputSections">
        <section id="incomingMoney">
            <h3>Please Enter Your Budget</h3>
            <input type="number" id="incomingCashInput" class="inputs" name="incoming_Cash_Input"><br>
            <button id="incomingCalcButton">Calculate</button>
        </section>

        <section id="enterExpenses">
            <h3>Please Enter Your Expense</h3>
            <input type="text" id="expenseName" class="inputs" name="expense_Name">
            <h3>Please Enter Expense Amount</h3>
            <input type="number" id="expenseAmount" class="inputs" name="expense_Value"><br>
            <button id="expenseButton">Add Expense</button>
        </section>
    </div>
    <section id="calculations" class="calcs">
        <div class="budget calcs">
            <h3>Budget</h3><br>
            <img src="money_icon.png" class="moneyIcon calcIcon"><br>
            <section id="budgetIncoming">

            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="expenses calcs">
            <h3>Expenses</h3><br>
            <img src="expense_icon.png" class="expenseIcon calcIcon"><br>
            <section id="expenseIncoming">

            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="balance calcs">
            <h3>Balance</h3><br><br>
            <img src="budget_icon.png" class="budgetIcon calcIcon"><br>
            <section class="balanceIncoming">

            </section>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="expenses expContainer" >
        <div class="expContainer">
            <h4>Expense Title</h4>
            <section class="titleExpenses expContainer" id="title_Expenses">

            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="expContainer">
            <h4>Expense Value</h4><br><br>
            <section class="valueExpenses" id="value_Expenses">
                
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="expContainer">
            <h4>Edit</h4>
            <section class="deleteExpenses" >

            </section>
        </div>

    </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood well what you want to achieve.
But maybe this example can help you move your project forward:
  [a link on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6b5rpxzf/)

Comment: That does help, I have been working on the calculation part as well. Now for my question above, I am trying to have my expense names and values stay written to the page. For instance, if the user enters Power 150, Mortgage 900, and Car Pmt 200 I'd like it to show all of those as opposed to now where it replaces the user input each time. Thanks for the help so far!